# CoreData запрос

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Народ, привет! Не могу сделать простейщий запрос.
Имеем Entity: Здания, где есть 3 параметра: Название, Адрес и Площадь.

Собственно вопрос: Как мне запросом вывести Названия всех Зданий в одну таблицу?

Answer (score 0):

Вот что придумал:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Здания"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"Названия"]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *dicArray = [_persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:dicArray forKeys:[dicArray valueForKey:@"Названия"]];

NSArray *array = [dictionary allKeys];
```

Done: у меня в array только названия зданий.